# Android Automotive media Player Application

Tags: media-player

how does the Media app know/ displayed once we add media files to local storage?

TIA.

Comment: Some specific media playes (for example, MX Player) have in-app refresh features (e.g., pull-down refresh is a setting in aforementioned).  VLC also has a trigger in the settings somewhere to rebuild database.  I'm unsure if AA native UI has anything, though.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of storage permissions and file scanning in n intervals